# Asserting a failed login attempt on Simpletest

Tags: 7, testing

I want to test a module that adds an additional login validation clause. Only users whitelisted somewhere else are allowed to log in to the system.

In order to test this behaviour with Simpletest, I would like to assert that a random user has no access to the system.

I have tried to create this random user and then to call `drupalLogin()`. Unfortunately, my test fails because `drupalLogin()` is checking whether the log in succeeded, by calling `assertLink()` internally.

This is what I have tried:

```
    $user = $this->drupalCreateUser(array());
    $user->roles[] = 'authenticated user';
    user_save($user);

    // Try to login with it
    // It fails, because of the additional validation performed by my custom module
    $this->drupalLogin($user);

    // I would like to assert it here instead:
    $this->assertFalse(isset($this->loggedInUser->uid));
```

What should I do in order to avoid the assertion to fail at `drupalLogin()`, so that I can assert it myself?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else wonders about this... It wasn't difficult, but I didn't realise at first that it can be done by copying part of the [DrupalWebTestCase::drupalLogin() source code](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!simpletest!drupal_web_test_case.php/function/DrupalWebTestCase%3A%3AdrupalLogin/7):

```
$edit = array(
  'name' => $user->name,
  'pass' => $user->pass_raw,
);
$this->drupalPost('user', $edit, t('Log in'));
```

And then asserting that the user could not log in:

```
// Assert that the user is not logged in
$this->assertNoLink(t('Log out'), 0, t('User not logged in.'), t('User login'));
```